# How to use sharedpref.edit() only once

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a code where I called sharedPref.edit() and sharedPref.apply() multiple times. How to make convert it to call only once.

```
if (success) {
                                val data = response.getJSONObject("data")
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true).apply()
                                sharedPreferences.edit()
                                    .putString("user_id", data.getString("user_id")).apply()
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name", data.getString("name"))
                                    .apply()
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("email", data.getString("email"))
                                    .apply()
                                sharedPreferences.edit()
                                    .putString("mobile_number", data.getString("mobile_number"))
                                    .apply()
                                sharedPreferences.edit()
                                    .putString("address", data.getString("address")).apply()

                                StyleableToast.Builder(this)
                                    .text("Welcome " + data.getString("name"))
                                    .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
                                    .textColor(Color.WHITE).show()

                                userSuccessfullyLoggedIn()
                            }
```

I want to use the method call only once.

> This can be called once, the returned editor instance can be stored in
> a variable and re-used.

How to do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These little steps will organize your code.

You can put it like this:

```
val editor =  sharedPreferences.edit()
```

Then use it :

```
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true)
```

And Add others values without ".apply()"

Then Put at the End:

```
 editor.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom Shared Preferences

```
class CustomSharedPreferences {

    companion object {

        private val PREFERENCES_USER_NAME = "preferences_user_name"
        private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

        @Volatile private var instance: CustomSharedPreferences? = null

        private val lock = Any()
        operator fun invoke(context: Context) : CustomSharedPreferences = instance ?: synchronized(lock){
            instance ?: makeCustomSharedPreferences(context).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }

        private fun makeCustomSharedPreferences(context: Context) : CustomSharedPreferences{
            sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            return CustomSharedPreferences()
        }
    }

    fun saveUser(name: String, email: String){
        sharedPreferences?.edit(commit = true){
            putString(PREFERENCES_USER_NAME, name)
        }
    }

    fun getUser() = sharedPreferences?.getString(PREFERENCES_USER_NAME, "")

}
```

You can save all information to SP in saveUser().